# Parsing JSON objects - skipping the first two elements

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and I am struggling to parse a JSON object that I am receiving form a URL. I am getting the following error:-

> ```
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
> ```

I know this is just unfamiliarity with the syntax and JSON files. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I want the element named `"Last"`. I know I need to get past the first two elements but I am not having any luck. I realize this will take someone 1 second to fix :)

```
import json
bstr = """{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
        {
            "MarketName": "USDT-BTC",
            "High": 2900,
            "Low": 2600.948,
            "Volume": 3938.44761207,
            "Last": 2785,
            "BaseVolume": 10845860.23439689,
            "TimeStamp": "2017-07-22T14:22:07.03",
            "Bid": 2785,
            "Ask": 2790.10954,
            "OpenBuyOrders": 3039,
            "OpenSellOrders": 610,
            "PrevDay": 2756.711,
            "Created": "2015-12-11T06:31:40.633"
        }
    ]
}"""
b = json.loads(bstr)
print(b["success"]["message"]["result"]["Last"])
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: `b['result'][0]['Last']` That's it.

Comment: Why are you trying to subscript `success` and `message` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: you made some errors with cases (`"Sessage"` vs `"success"`). Note that strings are case-sensitive.

If you parse the JSON, you obtain a **dictionary**. Now if you get the element of a dictionary (like `b["success"]`) you obtain the **value associated with the given key** (like `"success"`).

In your JSON, `"Success"` is associated with a boolean: `true`. You **can not obtain the element of a boolean** (like `b["success"]["message"]`).

What you probably want to do is print multiple parts of the JSON, you can do this by writing for instance:

```
print(b["success"],b["message"],b["result"][0]["Last"])
```

Which prints:

```
>>> print(b["success"],b["message"],b["result"][0]["Last"])
True  2785
```

The reason we can use `b["result"][0]["Last"]` is because the value associated with `"result"` is a **list**. We **use `[0]` to obtain the first element of that list**, and that element is **another dictionary**. We thus then lookup `"Last"` in that sub dictionary.

Comment: Thanks - this makes it much more clear. Much appreciated!